# Forward to https keeping the URL intact/complete

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, mod-rewrite

I want to forward all traffic to https.
There can be subdomains and subpaths in the URL that should stay intact.
Example:

```
http://subdomain.myDomain.me -> https://subdomain.myDomain.me
http://myDomain.me/subpath -> https://myDomain.me/subpath
http://subdomain.myDomain.me/subpath -> https://subdomain.myDomain.me/subpath
```

I tried the examples in [this neat evaluator](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) (link from [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/redirect-change-urls-or-redirect-http-to-https-in-apache-everything-you-ever)) with the following code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https:/$1
```

**In the evaluator, everything is fine.**
The real virtual host looks like this:

```
<virtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myDomain.me
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https:/$1
</VirtualHost>
```

When trying to acces the real site, this happens:

```
http://subdomain.myDomain.me -> http://subdomain.myDomain.me # fail - no https
http://myDomain.me/subpath -> https://myDomain.mesubpath # fail - subpath appended to top-level domain
http://subdomain.myDomain.me/subpath -> https://subdomain.myDomain.me/subpath # success
```

**What is wrong with this rewrite?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct rule is the following.

```
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

This however is not the recommended method to redirect HTTP requests to HTTPS. The preferred method is to use a redirect in your Apache confit to point to the SSL enabled site.

You can more about the preferred method at [the Apache Httpd wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RedirectSSL).

Comment: Thank you. Your code works when I use Chrome. Interestingly, with Firefox (my default) it's not working. The redirect approach seems not suitable for me as I don't want to add rules for every subdomain and subpage - I just want them to be forwarded to their https counterpart.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off # you can skip this if you want to redirect everything
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NC]
```

If that's not working try:

```
RewriteRule ^(/(.*))?$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Don't forget to send the `R=301` flag to make the redirect permanent.